# Does the word "since" ever have a meaning of "thus", "hereby" ones?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

Here is a sentence from "Programming Perl":

> They [*constructors mentioned above in the book* — OP's note] don’t really care whether they were invoked from tie, nor do any of the other methods in the class, **since** you can always invoke them directly if you’d like.

In my dictionary *since* is translated only as "because", "from the time when" etc. But it appears to me that in this sentence *since* is a synonym of *thus*, as "you can always invoke them directly if you’d like" is the *consequence* of the first part, rather than the *cause* of it.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: @J.R., so you mean that `since` never has a meaning of `thus`?

Comment: I see the word "since" in this sentence as actually meaning **because**. Being a programmer (though I don't know Perl), I vaguely understand what it's saying, and from what I see, it does mean because.

"They don’t really care whether they were invoked from tie, nor do any of the other methods in the class, **because** you can always invoke them directly if you’d like."

This means they don't care *etc etc* **because** you can always invoke them directly.

Comment: [One of the authors of that book](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist) is a regular contributor here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think the sentence is a result clause that should be prefixed with *thus*. *Since* is used correctly and means *because*. Here is how I get it:

> They don’t really care whether they were invoked from tie, *nor do any of the other methods in the class*, since you can always invoke them directly if you’d like.

The italicized part serves as an additional info for the first clause and could be dropped without losing any meaning.

> They don’t really care whether they were invoked from tie, since or [because] you can always invoke them directly if you’d like.

Answer (score 2):

Is your assumption correct?  That depends on which assumption you're referring to.

One of your assumptions appears to be that *thus* and *because* cannot be used interchangably, that *because* is used to indicate causation, and *thus* is used to indicated consequence.  And then there's a second assumption, that the word *since* should be used only as a synonym for *because*, but not for *thus*.

I have no problem with the sentence as written (neither did the publisher, apparently).  Since the sentence appears to be okay, we need to figure out where the erroneous assumption is.

I think the line between cause and consequence is a blurry one:

> The egg broke because I dropped it.
>   I dropped the egg; therefore, it broke.

I also like the way [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/since) wrote their definition of *since*:

> used when explaining why someone does something or why a situation exists

This definition keeps the word versatile; without a constraint that the word can be used as a synonym for *because*, but not *thus* (or vice-versa).  That's more in line with how I've observed the use of these terms:

> I had to pay a fine because the book was overdue.
>   Because the book was overdue, I had to pay a fine.
>   The book was overdue, so I had to pay a fine.

Those are all fine; so are:

> Since the book was overdue, I had to pay a fine.
>   I had to pay a fine since the book was overdue.

In short, even though many definitions of *since* includes *because* but not *thus*, that doesn't imply that *since* can't be used to indicate consequence, in addition to cause.